# how to display only the sub category names of the taxonmoy

Tags: taxonomy

I have using Taxonomy in filterable functionality and its working is fine. but its always showing the parent category names and sub category names if they have the post.
How to hide the sub category names while have the data.

Please look on my code for better understanding.

```
<?php
             $terms = get_ancestors("categoryproduct");
             $count = count($terms);
             echo '<ul id="portfolio-filter" class="prd_filter_title">';
             echo '<li><a href="#all" title="">All</a></li>';
             if ( $count > 0 ){

                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                        $termname = strtolower($term->name);
                        $termname = str_replace(' ', '-', $termname);
                        echo '<li><a href="#'.$termname.'" title="" rel="'.$termname.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
                    }
             }
             echo "</ul>";
        ?>
```

for example: i have a product named as "**Product 1**", **category = "food"**, **sub categories = food 1, food 2**.

so, if assigning category and sub categories to this product will showing all categories (parent category, two sub categories) names in the front end.
How to show only the main category name in the filterable **ul** **li** section?

Please check the front end sceenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/qEagxA5rkhZ

```
 <?php 
            $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'products', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
            $count =0;
        ?>

        <div id="portfolio-wrapper">
            <div id="portfolio-list">

            <?php if ( $loop ) : 

                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php
                    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'categoryproduct' );

                    if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
                        $links = array();

                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) 
                        {
                            $links[] = $term->name;
                        }
                        $links = str_replace(' ', '-', $links); 
                        $tax = join( " ", $links );     
                    else :  
                        $tax = '';  
                    endif;
                    ?>

                    <?php $infos = get_post_custom_values('_url'); ?>

                    <div class="portfolio-item <?php echo strtolower($tax); ?> all">

                         <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

                         <div class="thumb">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(300, 300) ); ?>


                                </a>
                        </div> 



                    </div>




                <?php endwhile; ?>



            <?php endif; ?>
```

this will be the filtering items loop. its working fine. only want to show the main category in the filtering title sections.

Please let me know the solution.
Thanks